# how to make centre align divs vertically and horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

could you please  tell me how to make centre align divs vertically and horizontally ? I Have two divs I need to display on centre of page .Secondly there is some margin between the  two divs how to remove that margin here is my code

```
  <div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid red;"class="moreinfo">


</div> 
       <div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid red" class="moreinfo">


</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tbnd90fd/

I do like that
https://jsfiddle.net/tbnd90fd/1/

best way?

```
.maindiv{

    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 45%;
}
```

I give top and left ..is it the best way ? and how to remove margins?

Comment: ok I wil, try and update you

Comment: Please take the time to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and learn how to ask questions on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `.maindiv` remove `text-align`, set `left` and `right` to `50%` and, finally, add one more line `transform:translate(-50%, -50%);`.
By this way, `maindiv` upper left corner will be placed in the center and `transform` will "pull" back up and left for half size of itself (and You don't need `margin:auto` anymore).

There is example :

```css
.moreinfo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.maindiv
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
  <div class="maindiv"> 
      <div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid red;"class="moreinfo"></div><div style="height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid red;" class="moreinfo"></div> 
</div>
```

**Update :**

The `divs` are treated as inline-elements. Just as a space or line-break between two spans would create a gap, it does between inline-blocks. You could give them a negative margin... in this example, You could change, in `moreinfo`, `margin:0px` to `margin:-2px;`.

There is [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/xdfL692v/1/)

Comment: why the margin is present between the divs

Comment: like @G.L.P. wrote, You have to remove all spaces between those two inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div class="moreinfo">        
    </div><div class="moreinfo"></div> <!-- Remove the spaces -->
```

CSS:

```
.moreinfo {
   display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px; height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

For Reference: Try this **[Link](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**

Comment: but how to make center align ?..horizontally and vertically  center